# WPF Treeview single objects as child nodes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I'm not quite sure if a TreeView is the thing I should use in my situation but it seems to be a logical choice. I'm trying to create a TreeView which gets populated by a list of ObjectA.

ObjectA looks like this:

```
public class ObjectA{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public ObjectB CurrentChild { get; set; }
    public ObjectB PreviousChild { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see ObjectA contains two childs of ObjectB. One is the current child and the second one is the previous child.

ObjectB looks like this:

```
public class ObjectB{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

How can I create a TreeView which Displays the "DisplayName" of ObjectA and if you expand ObjectA you can see two child nodes, one is the CurrentChild and the other one is the PreviousChild? I know I could create a List of ObjectB as property of ObjectA and store CurrentChild & PreviousChild inside of this list rather than using two properties and with such a list I could do easy stuff with an "HierarchicalDataTemplate" but I would like to know if it's possible to create a TreeView or another WPF control which can display these objects without altering the actual "Backend"-code. I would appreciate your help :)

Comment: Depending on how you define "expand ObjectA" you may perhaps use a ListBox and show the two children when a ListBoxItem is selected (by a Trigger on its IsSelected property).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really don't want to change your object model, you could go for the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` too, and use a converter to the binding object:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionAObjects}">
  <TreeView.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding, Converter={StaticResource MyCollectionConverter}}" ...>
```

The converter class should be something simple like...

```
public class MyCollectionConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var result = new ObservableCollection<ObjectB>();
        result.Add(((ObjectA)value).CurrentChild);
        result.Add(((ObjectA)value).PreviousChild );
        return result;
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

Don't forget to declare the namespace of your converter (if it is not in the same as your WPF View class) and add it on your local resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <local:MyCollectionConverter x:Key="MyCollectionConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: As a note, it makes no sense to return an ObservableCollection from the converter. There will never be any items added or removed, so notifying about it is pointless. You may simply return `new ObjectB[] { a.CurrentChild, a.PreviousChild }`

Comment: That's true.. And also If he is not editing the original model, he will also not notify changes on child objects in any way.Thanks @Clemens!

Comment: My models are actually different, I just made up ObjectA and ObjectB because they are representing what I want to accomplish without the stuff that is not important for the question, so a ObservableCollection is perfect. And the answer is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Except one small thing, I had to modify the converter, so it checks if the value object is ObjectB because it always was whenever I expanded an item in the treeview.

Comment: Good point, I forgot about that... But I guess this provides a general idea of what needs to be done if someone needs this information in the future